# React native app doesn't connect to VPN server

Tags: react-native, vpn

I developed a mobile app which is connected to APIs with `axios`. It was working fine before. But now those APIs can only be accessed through an VPN because server is restricted. So, I connected to the VPN with mobile and accessed those APIs URL successfully with the browser. But with the VPN on, I can't access the same APIs through mobile app. It doesn't allow me. Since, I can access them from browser, I think, VPN connection is okay, but I am not sure (Server is not my task. It belongs to devops).

This is how send the axios request.

```
return axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: `${URL.URL_VAR}/api/oauth/oauth/token`,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    data: bodyFormData
  }).then(function (response) {
    console.log("response" + response.status);
    return response;
  }).catch(function (response) {
    console.log("Get login error: " + JSON.stringify(response.message));
    return response;
  });
```

This is my `manifest.xml` file.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  package="com.campaign">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
      android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" tools:targetApi="28"
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

This is my network security config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <!-- For React Native Hot-reloading system -->
        <!-- If you are running on a device insert your computer IP -->
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">mydomain.io</domain>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </domain-config>

    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false" />
</network-security-config>
```

All of these were working perfectly before restricting to a VPN.

Since I am a beginner, what kind of areas I should be looking for to fix to solve this problem? Does this have to do anything with the app or, do I have have to change anything in the server? Please help.

Comment: When you was testing it from Browser was it locally - in the same Network? Maybe your Server has something like a Whitelist and the Device has to be named there.

Comment: When testing from the browser, it was in the same network. Environment wasn't changed. I whitelisted the server domains in network security config file. But, yeah, I'll have a look if I should whitelist from server. But I could access the same API through browser in same device.

Answer (score 0):

Is your vpn tunneling your entire network? Or is it a built-in vpn for the browser? on iOS it would show a VPN logo on the top and in android there would be a vpn client in your notification center. Otherwise traffic is not being routed through the VPN.